# Emulating IE in Ubuntu

Tags: 12.10, emulation, testing, ie

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install IE9, IE8, or IE7 in ubuntu 12.04.LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190425/how-to-install-ie9-ie8-or-ie7-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts)

I need to test my web site in Internet Explorer. Unluckily, I can't move it to Windows and run there. So what is the easiest  way to test it?

Comment: Yes it is a duplicate