# Javascript for ie8

Tags: playonlinux, javascript

I need to use internet explorer 8 with javascript for a program I need for work.  I've installed ie8 and tried to install java for windows using playonlinux but the sits still says I don't have javascript when I try to open the page.  How do I get javascript running on ie8 on ubuntu?  I'm running 13.04.
THanks!

Comment: Javascript has nothing to do with Java. The people behind Javascript just took the name because Java was so popular. At least that's the story I've heard...

Comment: Microsoft made Windows Virtual PC VHDs for testing websites with different Internet Explorer versions. I would use those.

Comment: adding to @Rinzwind 's comment:http://askubuntu.com/questions/190425/how-to-install-internet-explorer-multiple-versions

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is different from Java.Java is an Object oriented language whereas JavaScript is client side scripting language which need to be enabled from your browser properties.It comes built in with every browser.
A [tutorial](http://support.microsoft.com/gp/howtoscript) on how to enable JavaScript in any Browser

[Difference B/w Java and JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java)