# Error while installing extension pack on Oracle VM VirtualBox

Tags: installation, virtualbox, oracle

I have installed Oracle VM VirtualBox on Ubuntu 13.10 and I am trying to install IE8 on Windows 7 from Terminal as suggested in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/223412/212399). I am running following command on Terminal:

```
$ curl -s https://raw.github.com/xdissent/ievms/master/ievms.sh | IEVMS_VERSIONS="8" bash
```

However, after downloading the appropriate package Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack, when it is getting installed, I am receiving following error on Terminal.

```
Installing Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack 
from /home/ninad/.ievms/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.3.2.vbox-extpack
0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to install 
    "/home/ninad/.ievms/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.3.2.vbox-extpack"
VBoxManage: error: The installer failed with exit code 1: 
VBoxManage: error: (gksu:8005): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 
    IA__gdk_window_set_opacity: assertion 'GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), 
    component ExtPackManager, interface IExtPackManager
VBoxManage: error: Context: "int handleExtPack(HandlerArg*)" 
    at line 1143 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp

ERROR: Failed to install Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack 
   from /home/ninad/.ievms/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.3.2.vbox-extpack, 
   error code (1)
```

Please guide me how do I continue the installation of IE8 on Windows7 in Oracle VM VirtualBox.

---

**Update (23 Nov 2013)** :

- Tried method as suggested by @rajagenupula. However, VirtualBox says that *the extension pack is already installed with the same version. Do you want to reinstall it?* I think this may be bacause somewhere amongst my multiple attempts, it has already been installed. I do not think reinstalling is going to help here.
- Ran command `$ sudo apt-get install unar` to install unar package. Without this, I was getting

  ```
  ERROR: Linux support requires unar (sudo apt-get install for Ubuntu/Debian)
  ```
- Now trying to download 716 MB file of VM for IE8 by the same curl command for IE8 VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there are quite a few steps to install Oracle VM VirtualBox extension package.

After installation of Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.3.2.vbox-extpack was successful,

1. I tried to run

   `$ curl -s https://raw.github.com/xdissent/ievms/master/ievms.sh 
   | IEVMS_VERSIONS="8" bash`

   This gave me an error

   ```
   ERROR: Linux support requires unar (sudo apt-get install for Ubuntu/Debian)
   ```

   I resolved it bu running `$ sudo apt-get install unar` on Terminal.
2. Then I re-ran command

   `$ curl -s https://raw.github.com/xdissent/ievms/master/ievms.sh 
   | IEVMS_VERSIONS="8" bash`

   However, it gave me an error which said something like `Unable to extract IE6_WinXP.zip from /home/ninad/.ievms/IE6_WinXP.zip.`

   When I checked in this folder, (by showing hidden files <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) it showed IE6_WinXP.zip file which was just 1.6 MB in size. I deleted that and re-run the `curl` command. Then it downloaded the required package for IE8 successfully and installed.
3. After installation was complete, when it came to a point of starting the newly installed VM, it gave an error of

   > Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Tux 3 VT-x features
   >   locked or unavailable in MSR (VERR_VMX_MSR_LOCKED_OR_DISABLED).

   At this point, my Virtual Machine was looking like it is installed but in *Powered off* mode.

   [image: IE8 WinXP machine in power off state]

   When I tried to start it, it gave me the following error -

   [image: VT-x error]

   I resolved it by referring to answer of [How do I enable hardware visualization technology (VT-x) for use in Virtualbox?](https://askubuntu.com/q/256792/212399) i.e. by enabling visualization in BIOS Advance settings (To enter BIOS, I press F2 before Ubuntu's grub menu appears when computer is starting).

Once this last piece of error taken care of, my Oracle VM VirtualBox started showing IE8 on WinXP and also powered it on correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

with out knowing what is in the script we cant help you much better. Any way you are trying to install extension pack and you can do it by downloading from [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) .

[click here to start download](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.2/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.3.2-90405.vbox-extpack)

Then open it with virtualbox. It will install automatically there after.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Its best to get it from the downloads page rather than the click here link because that is linking to a very old version.