# How to install Internet Explorer 11 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: wine, winetricks, web-development, ie

I would like to run IE 11 for development purpose ...

I found that I can install IE from 1 to 9 using winetricks, but no IE 11.

I also found this post [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190425/how-to-install-internet-explorer-multiple-version), but the suggested tool is working only for 30 days. Is there a way to install IE11 for unlimited time ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: No. You have to have a valid Windows product key to install and use IE for more than 30 days.

Comment: That post was about virtualization and he wants to know about running it with something like Wine. Your comment is irrelevant. Did you even read that Ask Ubuntu post he mentioned?