# Internet Explorer is not being installed, and getting stopped in between?

Tags: wine, software-installation, ie

I recently tried to install Internet Explorer in Ubuntu 12.04 with the help of Wine. I did the following:

1. I downloaded IE 8 for Vista. It installed, but did not work properly.
2. I could not figure out how to exactly uninstall it, so I deleted the IE folder. Then I downloaded IE 7 for XP. However it did not install completely.
3. But now I figured out how to uninstall a Wine software. So I removed Internet Explore through Wine. Then I tried to install IE 10 for 8.

It now gives me an error message: `Internet explorer did not finish installing.` What should I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet explorer doesn't work well in wine.

Use [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and the VMs from [IE Virtual tools](http://modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads).

Answer (score 2):

As you can see [on WineHQ](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=25), the ratings for Internet Explorer in Wine are very bad. Quite simply, *Internet Explorer is not expected to work well in Wine*, unless you are trying to run Internet Explorer 3.01 for Windows 3.11, which actually has a "Gold" rating (the next best one).

I would suggest you install something like [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and actually run Windows within Ubuntu instead, that way you'll be running Internet Explorer natively which will work a lot better than running it with Wine.

Also, see this possible duplicate question: [How to install Internet Explorer (multiple versions)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190425/how-to-install-internet-explorer-multiple-versions)

Comment: With the Virtual Machine, you can get one (or more) from [here](http://modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads)