# Install IE from ubuntu trusty

Tags: 14.04, wine, ie

please help me guys, 
i want to install internet explorer with wine 
with execute command ./ies4linux
buth when i execute, appear IEs4Linux 2 is developed to be used with recent Wine versions (0.9.x). It seems that you are using an old version. It's recommended that you update your wine to the latest version (Go to: winehq.com).

can someone help me ?

Comment: What does `wine --version` and  `sudo apt-cache policy wine` say ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ies4linux installation is failing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/723052/ies4linux-installation-is-failing)

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Referring to this answer ([ies4linux installation is failing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/723052/ies4linux-installation-is-failing?rq=1)), the error message is a false alert.

---

The official [Ubuntu package information](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/wine) says that the current wine version for Ubuntu 14.04 in universe repository is 1.6.2. You should be able to update to this version when Universe repository is enabled (--> [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository))

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

You can also install a newer version of Wine via ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends wine-staging
sudo apt-get install winehq-staging
```

Found [here](http://linuxdaddy.com/blog/install-wine-1-9-on-ubuntu/)