# Installing Oracle Service Cloud (Legacy Name: RightNow CRM)?

Tags: wine, playonlinux, cloud, oracle, ie

I was wondering if anyone has had experience with using Oracle Service Cloud also known as RightNow CRM, on Ubuntu?

It requires Internet Explorer or Microsoft Edge to install locally, and I have seen articles pertaining how to 'install' IE on Linux with high levels of uncertainty, but that's only part of the issue. I was thinking somehow through Wine or Playonlinux I would be able to get IE working and run the installer/program in Wine.

Another thought would be using Microsoft's VMs for webtesting [seen here.](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/#downloads)

Worst case I know I could virtualize a Windows guest OS. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Note that Wine have a browser [gecko](https://wiki.winehq.org/Gecko). You might have seen Wine asks whether you want download it. I have no idea how compatible it is with IE, but worth at least trying. You might also be interested [in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190425/how-to-install-internet-explorer-multiple-versions).